# Excluding first match on a regexp

Tags: javascript

I have the following regexp:

https://jsfiddle.net/czbw3c1f/

```
var str = "111222 111 111 22111";
var reg = /1+/g;

console.log(str.match(reg));
```

Its finding all the groups of number `1` in the `str` string. How can I exclude the first match from the regexp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`[].slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get a subarray from the position 1 to the end:

```
(str.match(reg) || []).slice(1);
```

The `|| []` part is needed in case there is no match and `''.match` returns null.

Comment: Is it possible through the regex? In order to apply it to a `replace`?

Comment: [`String.prototype.replace`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) sets the `reg.lastIndex = 0` at the beginning. So I don't think you can do this with native methods, but maybe you can keep calling `reg.exec(str)` and do the replacements manually.